# How do you allow buffering up to a certain timestamp with react-player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-streaming, react-player

If you want a video streaming an hls or mpeg-dash stream to only play up to a certain timestamp and stop playing/buffering after that timestamp, how would you do that using [react-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player)?